# How to hide Google Translate toolbar popup?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need to hide Google translate toolbar that appears after the user selects a language.

[image: Google Translate Toolbar]

I did my research and most answers point use the following code to hide the popup:

```
.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
}

body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

However, on my project, the solution is working partially: if I use display none on the `.skiptranslate` class, the translation dropdown will stop working entirely.

I think google changed the structure of the popup recently as legacy solutions are not working for me.

I also tried to inspect the element and find a custom solution without success, any tips?

These are my current overwrite to the Google Translate dropdown:

```
.goog-te-gadget-icon {
    display: none;
}

.goog-te-gadget-simple {
    background-color: #ecebf0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    zoom: 1;
}

.goog-te-gadget-simple span {
    color: #000 !important;
}

body {
    top: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: if you find any solution, please post as answer here because i also face same problem / issue. the language dropdown menu is not working / it disappear if i use .skiptranslate {display: none;}

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by tracking the class name. If you expand the 'skiptranslate' div, you'll find an iframe that is responsible for the toolbar. Track the class name of this iframe and make the display property as none.

```
 .VIpgJd-ZVi9od-ORHb-OEVmcd {
    display: none; // add !important if required 
  }
```